# Nested underlined text elements

Tags: css

I have in text paragraphs some rather large portions of underlined texts. Many of them go over several lines.

Within those underlined elements, in some cases I have elements that should be underlined themselfes. Here, the underline of the outer underlined element should go a little down in order to make the underline of the inner underlined elments visible. Look at the third line of my mockup and you will understand what I mean (at least I hope so). "querit" and "Epicurae" are underlined within underlined elements.

[image]

How can I achieve this in CSS? With `text-decoration: underline` the underlines collapse and you won't see which elements are nested underlined elements. On the other hand, `display:inline-block; border-bottom:1px solid black;` will just underline the last line.

Edit: The HTML for this mockup would look like this: (not particulary interesting, I guess)

```
<p> de con firt omniandabetisporatienimusi remprobist extrum etis e ipsaenderienimagnos <span class="underlined">quibus quidas mus, ines, quam Solostracum met ipsa horum mum, esispotatus con ipid  inprobus, que vollin que <span class="underlined">querit</span> pus nego mo <span class="underlined">Epicurae</span> id sitam mod etia et nectuas ent malosse te. quitus, essendolinxet ob utrus aleganesserisimone ne nitae lium vitae;  Metisquiamquae sid los plego ilius, andus adexperibus vitur. quod dictantum alt, num Toriae</span> conc ocorturaec </p>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `display: inline-block`. Say, we are using the tag `<span class="und">` for underlining something. For a nested one, use something like this:

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 15px;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
p {margin: 0 0 10px;}
.und {border-bottom: 1px solid; padding: 2px;}
.und .und {border-bottom: 1px solid; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, cumque! Facere iste, adipisci non quam molestias modi! Reprehenderit, quo officia est voluptatibus eum omnis magni voluptate. Similique, voluptatibus quasi dolore!</p>

<p><span class="und">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque quo ea natus deserunt praesentium laudantium similique, officia sequi unde provident quasi aliquid iure, tempora sunt quod doloremque, dolor. Voluptate, tempora! <span class="und">This is double underlined and doesn't break!</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor commodi adipisci similique eligendi a praesentium officia repudiandae quaerat ipsum placeat natus nemo, sit magnam laborum error vero, ullam officiis veniam!</span></p>
```

**Nested Items**

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {margin: 15px;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
p {margin: 0 0 10px; line-height: 1.5;}
.und {border-bottom: 1px solid; padding: 4px;}
.und .und {border-bottom: 1px solid; padding: 2px;}
.und .und .und {border-bottom: 1px solid; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, cumque! Facere iste, adipisci non quam molestias modi! Reprehenderit, quo officia est voluptatibus eum omnis magni voluptate. Similique, voluptatibus quasi dolore!</p>

<p><span class="und">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque quo ea natus deserunt praesentium laudantium similique, officia sequi unde provident quasi aliquid iure, tempora sunt quod doloremque, dolor. Voluptate, tempora! <span class="und">This is double underlined and <span class="und">triple consectetur adipisicing</span> doesn't break!</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. Dolor commodi adipisci similique eligendi a praesentium officia repudiandae quaerat ipsum placeat natus nemo, sit magnam laborum error vero, ullam officiis veniam!</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Still, there remain two problems for this clever solution: 1. The padding between text and underline remains always the same, whether there is another nested underlined element on this line (or in it at all) or not. I'd prefer the underline to be as close to the text as possible. 2. A third level of nesting won't work (unfortunately, I have these cases too).

Comment: @cis Shall we try a `line-height` fix?

Comment: @cis Looks like it. It is a limitation of the browser, where you cannot have a negative padding, which correctly sets the border and you cannot change the underline's location. So, well, we can use double underline. Let me try that.

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar Thank you again! Not exactely what I wanted, but it works, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The more modern approach would be to either use [`text-underline-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-position)

```css
.underlined{
  text-decoration:underline;
  text-underline-position: under;
}
.underlined .underlined{
  text-underline-position: auto;
}
```

```html
<p> de con firt omniandabetisporatienimusi remprobist extrum etis e ipsaenderienimagnos <span class="underlined">quibus quidas mus, ines, quam Solostracum met ipsa horum mum, esispotatus con ipid  inprobus, que vollin que <span class="underlined">querit</span> pus nego mo <span class="underlined">Epicurae</span> id sitam mod etia et nectuas ent malosse te. quitus, essendolinxet ob utrus aleganesserisimone ne nitae lium vitae;  Metisquiamquae sid los plego ilius, andus adexperibus vitur. quod dictantum alt, num Toriae</span> conc ocorturaec </p>
```

or if you want more fine grained control, and more nested levels use [`text-underline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset) (*i am also throwing some [`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style) for style*)

```css
.underlined{
  text-decoration:underline;
  text-underline-offset: 4px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
.underlined .underlined{
  text-underline-offset: 1px;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  text-decoration-color:red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
}
.underlined .underlined .underlined{
  text-underline-offset: 8px;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p> de con firt omniandabetisporatienimusi remprobist extrum etis e ipsaenderienimagnos <span class="underlined">quibus quidas mus, ines, quam Solostracum met ipsa horum mum, esispotatus con ipid  inprobus, <span class="underlined">que vollin que <span class="underlined">querit</span> pus</span> nego mo <span class="underlined">Epicurae</span> id sitam mod etia et nectuas ent malosse te. quitus, essendolinxet ob utrus aleganesserisimone ne nitae lium vitae;  Metisquiamquae sid los plego ilius, andus adexperibus vitur. quod dictantum alt, num Toriae</span> conc ocorturaec </p>
```